# Need to find largest and smallest values from user input

Tags: python-3.x

Input may contain strings as well but the code should continue, input is 7,2, bob, 10, 4

Need help to find largest and smallest from user input data and current code is only printing last entry

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")

if largest is None:
    largest = num
elif num > largest:
    largest = num

if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num


print("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: when you want to link together 2 strings together, you use '+', not the comma. You cannot link a string and an integer together. If you want to, you would firstly have to transform the integer into a string type. This can be done using the built-in function `str()`. Your prints would look like this : `print ("Maximum is  "+str(largest))`

Answer (score 1):

the program will work with the program code below:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
            smallest = num


print("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
            smallest = num
the program code will work with below

print("Maximum is", largest)
print ("Minimum is", smallest)

Comment: please format your answer instead of flooding the comments section with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `min()` and `max()` functions. The code would be the following:

```
while True:
    num = input('Enter more than a number separated by a comma: ')
    n = num.split(',')
    print(n)
    if len(n) >= 2:
        for i in range(len(n)):
            highest = max(n)
            lowest = min(n)
        print('Highest number: ' + highest)
        print('Lowest number: ' + lowest)
    else:
        print("Please,  at least enter 2 numbers separated by ','")
```

**SUMMARY:**

- The input we enter is stored in a variable called `num`
- We separate the input values using a comma
- We print the variable `n`, of type **list**
- If we have at least inputed *two* different numbers, we will have a for loop repeat the number of numbers we inputed
- We store the highest number in a variable called `highest`
- We store the lowest number in a variable called `lowest`
- We print out the highest and lowest numbers

**I HOPE THIS HELPED**

I have checked the code and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:
First, your if statements, to pull the largest number and smallest number, are outside of the `while true` loop. So indent the maximum and minimum calculations to include them in the loop.

Second, your `try` and `except` will check for a number and print `invalid input` when a string is used... but you have are still using the the input in the rest of your code. You need to add `continue` to the `except` block to start the `while` loop again.

Comment: Let's just say `continue` and call it a day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = None
s = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        fnum= int(num)
        if l is None:
            l = fnum
        elif fnum>l:
            l=fnum
        if s is None:   # get smallest value
            s = fnum
        elif fnum < s:
            s = fnum
    except:
        print("Invalid Input")
        
print("Maximum", l)
print("Smallest", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok let us notice that python 2.x will not give you expected results with :

```
num = input(.....)
```

so you need to use:

```
num = raw_input(.....)
```

while python 3.x doesn't have `raw_input` function
so you need to use:

```
num = input(.....)
```

It is a matter of python versions.
I hope I was clear.